# How can I enable ActiveX in IE8 on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, com, internet-explorer-8, activex

I've created a COM assembly using C#.  I set my IE 8 browser settings to low on my XP development PC, and I can use JavaScript to successfully run the methods.

If I copy the assembly to a Windows Server 2008 VM, even if I set IE's security levels to low, disable "Protected Mode" and run IE 8 as Administrator, I still get error 429: "Automation server can't create object."

I've created a test application to ensure that using regasm worked, and that works fine.

Any suggestions as to how to get this working in IE 8 in Windows Server 2008 would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Document whether this is a 64-bit version of Windows.  Use the 64-bit version of Regasm if that's the case.

Comment: Both XP & Win Server 2008 are 32-bit.

Comment: What IE zone (My Computer, Local Intranet, Trusted Sites, Internet) are things running in?  If you check the zone security and go to custom settings, what is the "Initialize and script activex controls not marked safe for scripting" set to?

Comment: Running in localhost, which is in the Trusted Sites list.  In both local intranet and trusted sites, the setting is "Prompt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your JS has the COM object name spelled correctly? I just tested with low settings on Trusted Sites and was able to get the FSO working.

```
<HTML>
  <head>
    <script>
      function buttonClick()
      {
        alert('a');
        var x = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        alert('b');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id="button1" onClick="buttonClick()"/>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks for this... it is definitely the right spelling, because it works on my XP PC.  Your code above also works.  I have a feeling that the problem is that my assembly needs to be installed from an MSI file instead of just being registered via regasm.

Comment: Use the /codebase option when registering your COM object and see if that helps, because that is what puts the information in the registry.

Comment: John Koerner, you are a genius!!